# Как правильно запустить команду top через ssh?

Tags: unix, top, ssh, linux

Мне надо выполнить команду top на одной машине, находясь на другой. Я запускаю данную команду через ssh следующим образом:

**ssh 192.168.0.2 top**

Где 192.168.0.2 - аддрес машины, на которой надо запустить соотвественноОднако, результат удручающий:

**top: tcgetattr() failed: Invalid argument**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно обойти данную проблему?OS: TimeSystop version: 2.0.7

Answer (score 3):

Hадо использовать параметр -t для того, что бы переназначить терминал: **ssh -t 192.168.0.2 top**